# How to disable ads in JDownloader?

Tags: jdownloader

[image: screenshot]

Even when downloading [the "adware-free" installer](http://jdownloader.org/jdownloader2), the program still contains changing advertising banners which open browser when clicked. Is it possible to disable the ads?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Search for the following keywords in "advanced settings" and disable (uncheck) the options which appear.

```
premium alert
oboom
Special Deals
Donate
Banner
```

It may be necessary to restart JDownloader, but at least the banner on the main page is instantly gone.

[image]

Comment: Settings->Advanced Settings -> search for banner and disable it (https://board.jdownloader.org/showthread.php?t=66149)